# Is there a word in a dead or lost language that we lost the definition to?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, etymology, history, dictionaries

Is there a word we lost the definition to?
A word whose definition we lost to history?
Something that is a part of our history but we forgot the meaning with time

Comment: This would be more suitable for the Linguistics SE, since English is neither lost nor dead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about dead languages, not English

Comment: While _oil of mirbane_ has an accepted definition, nitrobenzene, no one knows where the Victorian scientist / chemist William A. Miller found the term _mirbane_ (or if he coined it). Chambers Twentieth Century Dictionary once worryingly (it prided itself on filtering out nonsense) 'defined' _mirbane_: 'an apparently meaningless word' (though it has been used as shorthand for the 3-word term).

Comment: **Manna** - nobody has the faintest idea what it is. There is a possibility that it means "What is it?" **OED:** *The etymological tradition preserved in Exodus 16:15 represents the word as having originated from the question man hū' ‘what is it’ (in Aramaic or supposed archaic Hebrew), which grammatically admits of being interpreted ‘it is mān ’*

Comment: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4683/what-is-the-most-common-classical-latin-word-that-we-dont-understand